# Prometheus exporter for eosio

Tags: eosjs, explorer

I am new to Prometheus and Grafana. I need **Prometheus eos exporter** for the purpose of **Eosio** private blockchain dashboard. I researched but didn't get any expected results. I need to show the eos node (multi-node) data (chain, blocks, transactions etc.) using **Grafana** and **Prometheus**. Can `eosjs` used with the Prometheus? Any help would be appreciated.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

For some simple stats, you can use https://eos.io/build-on-eosio/eosio-explorer/ which works as a GUI and can be repurposed in a dashboard.

For something more complex, you probably would want to use `DFuse`: https://dfuse.io/en/home/

Comment: I have a requirement for Prometheus and grafana because there are also other things other than eosio to use with these.

Comment: Can the system metrics like CPU, storage etc. for each peer node be shown in `eosio-explorer`?

Answer (score -1):

You want to expose the entire blockchain database to prometheus? Or just some statistics about current block number or something?

To me, sending all block data to prometheus is the wrong solution. Better to explore some of the history tools (hyperion, dfuse, cronicle).

Comment: Want to show statistics like current block no., TPS, transaction count etc. And user can search for information like any block or transaction.

Comment: Search for any block or transaction from within prometheus?  Sounds like the wrong thing.  Prometheus is for metrics, not undstructured data.   TPS would be reasonable.

Comment: But even if we keep the searching mechanism aside, do the Prometheus exporter for eos `nodeos`  is available?

Comment: I have a prometheus exporter for nodeos I use, but it doesn't do what you want.